# Removing consecutive duplicate characters from a std::string

Tags: c++, string

I'm currently trying to remove duplicate characters. For example:

- maaaaaaa becomes ma
- aaaaassssdddddd becomes asd

I have written the following piece of code:

```
string.erase(remove(string.find_first_of(string[i]) + 1, string.end(), string[i]), string.end());
```

but apparently std::string returns a pointer to the last + 1 character of the string, rather than the size, any ideas how I could remove string[i] from my string starting from the position next to that char?

Comment: Can you give an example input and desired output?

Comment: input: maaaaaaa
output: ma

input: aaasssssssssdddddd
output: asd

Comment: Are you trying to do exactly that with just a single call of the above code? Because you're specifying a single `i` there. I'm not asking for expected input and desired output for your ultimate goal, just for the given code sample (i.e. you probably need to include `i` in your expected input).

Comment: Nah, it was just a snipped of the code, Benjamin solved my problem, thanks though :)

Comment: @Frows: What would be your expected output for an input where the repetitions of a particular character are not necessarily all adjacent, such as this: "aaabbbaaabbb" ?  Because for the cases you described, you can do it all in one shot with `string.erase(std::unique(string.begin(), string.end()), string.end());` --

Comment: btw: Don't jam all that code on one line. It's a really poor way to communicate to other devs what the code is trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string.find_first_of` returns an integer position (and `string::npos` if not found). This is not compatible with`std::remove`, which expects iterators. You can convert from a position to an iterator by adding the position to the begin iterator.

```
char to_remove = string[i];
auto beg = string.begin() + string.find_first_of(to_remove) + 1;
auto new_end = std::remove(beg, string.end(), to_remove); 
string.erase(new_end, string.end());
```